# Value of <select><option> coming back as String instead of Long

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I'm facing the following error when adding a Contact with its email and the id of its associated Company :

```
2018-06-24 23:03:04.743  WARN 11360 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `org.vi.entities.Company` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('4'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.vi.entities.Company` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('4')
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 138] (through reference chain: org.vi.entities.Contact["company"])
```

i think the value of option send a String value instead of Long value, how can i solve this problem ?

```
<form class="forms-sample">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="contact.email"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="company" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company" [(ngModel)]="contact.company">
            <option *ngFor="let comp of companies" [value]="comp.id">{{comp.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-md-12 btn-outline-primary btn-fw btn-icon-text" (click)="saveContact(contact)">
        <i class="mdi mdi-file-check btn-icon-prepend"></i>
        Save
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md-12 btn-outline-secondary btn-fw btn-icon-text">
        <i class="mdi mdi-reload btn-icon-prepend"></i>
        Reset
      </button>
 </form>
```

model.contact.ts

```
import {Company} from './model.company';
export class Contact{
  email:string;
  phone:string;
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
  job:string;
  birthday:Date;
  company:Company
}
```

model.company.ts

```
export class Company{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  activity:string;
  address:string;
  city:string;
  logo:string;
}
```

Comment: **Please for more details see** [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978679/angular-5-json-parse-error-while-saving/50978782)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First shank you @Andriy for your reaction, Contact expect the entire Company object , so the solution is : `[ngValue]="comp"`

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="company" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company" [(ngModel)]="contact.company">
            <option *ngFor="let comp of companies" [ngValue]="comp" >{{comp.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`option`'s property `value` is always a string. Try to use `[ngValue]` instead.

```
<option *ngFor="let comp of companies" [ngValue]="comp.id">{{comp.name}}</option>
```

`option` element is overridden by `angular`'s [`NgSelectOption` directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption), which has `ngValue` input. `ngValue` may be of any type: boolean, object, integer, string, etc...

Comment: after using `[ngValue]="comp.id"` i get the same error :  `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of  org.vi.entities.Company (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of org.vi.entities.Company (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)`

Comment: did you try `[ngValue]="comp.id"`? no need in `{{}}`

Comment: what type of argument `Company`s constructor expects to receive. The error says, that it should not be an integer. You can test form's submit with POSTMAN and then apply correct types in angular

Comment: for more details please see [the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978679/angular-5-json-parse-error-while-saving/50978782)

Comment: i already did  it using ARC in chrome {"email":"root@gmail.com","phone":"632589714","firstName":"root","lastName":"root","birthday":null,"job":"root",                                                                   
"company":{ "id":1}
}